# String print out differently in Visual Studio and gcc

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc

I have created a simple project using Visual Studio 2012, and the code was compiled successfully, ran, and printed out as I expected (The fruit name is: apple). When I try to compile the same code with gcc, the print out looks different (The fruit name is: apple'). Where does the ' come from? Below is the code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

char * getCharValue(char line[]){
    char *pch = strchr(line, '='); //find where the equal sign is in the line
    char *pch1 = strchr(line, '\0'); // find the index of the end of the line
    char *info = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (pch1-pch-4));
    info[pch1-pch-5] = '\0';
    // copy the value to a new array then return the new char;
    memcpy(info, &line[pch-line+3], pch1-pch-5);
    return info;
}

int main()
{   
    char nameFileName[] = "Name.txt";       //register file name;
    char *nameValue;
    FILE *fid = fopen(nameFileName, "r");
    if (fid != NULL){   
        char line[150];
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fid) != NULL){   
            //if this line is not empty or a comment line
            if ((strncmp(line, "//", 2) != 0) && (line[0] != '\n')) {   
                if (strstr(line, "fruit_name") != NULL){
                    nameValue = getCharValue(line);
                    printf("The fruit name is: %s\n", nameValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Can not find the input file.");
        exit(-1);
    }
    fclose(fid);
    return 0;
}
```

The text file just contains 1 line as:

```
fruit_name           = 'apple'
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? How come it works with Visual Studio with no problem but cannot produce the right result using gcc?

Comment: The result depends on whether the single-line text file contains a `newline` or not. I don't get the `'` but I lose the last letter `e`. Seeing as you delimit the fruit name with `'` your code is conspicuous for the absence of any test for `'`. Instead, it makes assumptions about the amount of white-space padding there will be.

Comment: On a windows machine, a newline is stored in a file as a <CR><LF> pair. That usually gets translated to a single <LF> when being read by a C program. I suggest adding a `for` loop to print the decimal values in `line` to see if the <CR> is preserved in the gcc version.

Comment: At best your code is fragile. There are too many hard coded values. What is likely happening is that there is an extra whitespace character at the end of your input file in the gcc result. Due to the hard coded nature of your implementation that will cause the extra character.

Comment: Standard warning: do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends. In C you should not cast `void *`. This is different in C++! Also `main` has the [wrong signature](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.6) for a hosted environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have delimited with `'` but never check for them, and never check for a badly formatted file. Here is my revision. Note I don't cast `malloc()` and I don't use `sizeof(char)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

char * getCharValue(char line[]){
    char *pch, *pch1, *pch2, *info;
    int len;
    pch = strchr(line, '=');  // find where the equal sign is in the line
    if (pch == NULL)
        return NULL;
    pch1 = strchr(pch+1, '\''); // find the following quote mark
    if (pch1 == NULL)
        return NULL;
    pch2 = strchr(pch1+1, '\''); // find the following quote mark
    if (pch2 == NULL)
        return NULL;
    // copy the value to a new array then return the new char;
    len = pch2 - pch1 - 1;
    if (len <= 0)
        return NULL;
    info = malloc(len+1);
    memcpy(info, pch1+1, len);
    info[len] = '\0';
    return info;
}

int main()
{   
    char nameFileName[] = "Name.txt";       //register file name;
    char *nameValue = NULL;   //default
    FILE *fid = fopen(nameFileName, "r");
    if (fid != NULL){   
        char line[150];
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fid) != NULL){   
            //if this line is not empty or a comment line
            if ((strncmp(line, "//", 2) != 0) && (line[0] != '\n')) {   
                if (strstr(line, "fruit_name") != NULL){
                    nameValue = getCharValue(line);
                    if (nameValue == NULL)
                        printf("The file was badly formatted\n");
                    else
                        printf("The fruit name is: %s\n", nameValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Can not find the input file.");
        exit(-1);
    }
    fclose(fid);
    free(nameValue);    // won't matter if it is NULL
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
The fruit name is: apple
```

Comment: You should use `int main(void)` in C.

Comment: @Weather Vane, the code works in both Visual Studio and gcc, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
char *info = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (pch1-pch-4));  // 4 sheep??
info[pch1-pch-5] = '\0';                                    // 5 apples??
```

That's magic numbers for you, use them with no explanation and not even you will remember what they mean a few minutes later.

More specifically, the length of the strings is different in Windows and Linux because the line endings are different. On Windows the ending is `\r\n` and on Linux it's just `\n`, however your math (that `4`) only accounts for a 2 character ending (probably through trial and error).

You should test the actual ending instead (Macs' line ends with `\r` by the way) and do the math appropriately.

Comment: you're right, I should properly check the line endings and do the math in a general way instead of hard coded all the values.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest an even better approach to cope with variations on line endings which contribute to your problem.

As text files may migrate between systems that use various line endings, create code that strips away these line endings after `fgets()` be they `"\n"`, `"\n\r"`, `"\r\n"`, or `"\r"`: the 4 most popular.  `fgets()`, when reading in text mode, converts the *native* line ending to `'\n'`, but may not handle others.  Code can easily do the stripping itself.

Also cope with lines at the end of the file that may have *no* line ending.

All this takes 1 line

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fid) != NULL) {   

  // find length of `line` not containing `\r`, `\n`.
  line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = '\0';

  // Now code can continue in a uniform manner knowing the line ending is gone.
  if (strncmp(line, "//", 2)) {
```